# Having trouble centering a row widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `Row` widget on the bottom of the page that I can't center. I've tried all the `mainAxisAlignment`'s and `crossAxisAlignment`'s there are, as well as wrapping it in an `Align` widget and setting `alignment` to `alignment.center` and it's still on the left edge of the page. I've tried everything and am really stuck. Any help would be appreciated.
[The Page (Updated)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCiv6.jpg)

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
          centerTitle: true,
          elevation: 5,
          title: Text("Pathomatic")),
      body: Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: new Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: _cameraPreviewWidget(context),
                    ),
                    new Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: GestureDetector(
                          child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                            Positioned(
                              top: yPosition,
                              left: xPosition,
                              child: Container(
                                // padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 200.0, left: 20.0),
                                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
                                child:
                                    Image.asset('assets/images/crosshair.png'),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ]),
                          onPanUpdate: (tapInfo) {
                            setState(() {
                              xPosition += tapInfo.delta.dx;
                              yPosition += tapInfo.delta.dy;
                            });
                          }),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 5),
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      _cameraTogglesRowWidget(),
                      _mlTextWidget(),
                    ],
                  ),
                  _captureControlRowWidget(context),
                  //SizedBox(width: 50),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 5),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: if you create dartpad example, ill fix it for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually because the widget you are trying to center is actually stretching its container. Since it's the size of the screen, it's contents stick to the left. You should use the Flutter Inspector with [select widget mode](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/inspector#debugging-layout-issues-visually) to actually see how large your row is. Then everything will make much more sense.

In your code, your `Row` is stretching. Try

```
Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min
```

This should make it not grow. Alternatively, you can keep the row large but make it center its children:

```
Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.Center
```

Of course, with this approach its children will get close to each other in the center. You can use a `SizedBox` between them, or use some other way of spacing them apart.

Comment: I tried both your suggestions and the row items still don't move. I tried using `SizedBox` with a width of 50, and that got the camera icon in the middle. Is there a better way of doing it though? Should I change the `Expanded` widget to a `Container` instead?

Comment: Well, you can try using both of the things I said in the `Row`. The `Expanded` is irrelevant, it pushes this row below, which is good. Now I see the `Spacer()`, get rid of it, it's making your `Row` stretch, even when you use `MainAxisSize.min`

Comment: I tried both as well as removing the `Spacer()`. I updated the code and the image if you want to take a look. Still not centered. I guess I will have to use the `SizedBox` as last resort then. Just don't know if it will be centered across all devices.

Comment: Well, if you create a codepen I'll fix it there: https://codepen.io/pen/editor/flutter